# Efficient way to get all elements from a HashSet in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, hashset

Say, I have a HashSet with elements:

```
HashSet<int> hsData = new HashSet<int>();
```

and at some point I need to process those elements (one by one). I can of course convert it into an array and work with it that way:

```
int[] arr = hsData.ToArray();
```

but I'm not sure how efficient this conversion will be?

I see that people recommend using `foreach` on the HashSet itself, but due to architecture of my code, I cannot use it. I need something that can work as such:

> Is it the last element? If no, then get it and advance to next
>   element.

Comment: I didn't really understand the question... but... _"but I'm not sure how efficient this conversion will be?"_ did you check if it's significant and important? don't bother improve something that doesn't effect anything.

Comment: What's the "last element" in a HashSet? Sets aren't ordered.

Comment: @dtb I think he means the last element that is available.

Comment: Your explanation for why you can't use `foreach` seems really flimsy. It would really help if you could give more details here, as a `foreach` loop is by far the most natural solution to processing each item in a collection.

Comment: As @JonSkeet said - if you dont want to do any special processing for the last element, `foreach` would be the way to go. Your scenario is exactly what `foreach` was made for (unless there are other factors you did not include in your question). You could also use a `for` loop with `HashSet.Count` if you would like more control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you stated, converting to an array can have some performance drawbacks. What `foreach` does behind the scenes is get an enumerator in the `HashSet` and run through it.

`HashSet<T>` also implements `IEnumerable<T>`, which can be used to enumerate the collection in a much more efficient way. Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) for a reference on `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a foreach still if you'd like. Just keep a running counter of all the elements in the given list, decrement as you do an iteration, and do a comparison against the counter.

On the other hand, is turning it into an array a big deal? Is this operation happening 1000s of times?

Answer (score 0):

ToArray does not (yet) exist, but you can use [CopyTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.copyto?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_HashSet_1_CopyTo__0___)

Comment: [`ToArray()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray) exists as an extension method defined in the [`System.Linq.Enumerable` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable).  [Internally](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,783a052330e7d48d) it [calls](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,2677) [`ICollection<>.CopyTo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1.copyto).